# php variable value acts like zero

Tags: php, double

As I was working on a project I had an error which I couldn't understand why it is happening. On my code, I read a string from an API, which is a number but API return is string, so I make `$mynumber = floatval($mynumber);` and it works perfectly. But, after I make a math operation such as `$newnumber = $mynumber * 1.5;` I get a weird error.

```
echo $newnumber;
```

returns the number as "8.5E-6", which is perfectly fine and shows that `$newnumber`holds a value. Also `echo gettype($newnumber);` also returns "double" so everything seems perfect. But whenever I try to print the input as

```
echo number_format($newnumber);
```

it just prints "0" on the screen. Also, if I try to use that `$newnumber` variable on curl, I get error on the web site I'm trying to call APIs and it says "value can not be 0", so it seems like the value for that variable also passes as 0 on API request.

When I try to use `number_format` on the first variable, before multiplication, it returns the value without any problem, so the problem is not on the `number_format` function as well.

At this point I'm stuck and don't know how to solve this, any idea?

Comment: the original number's  value is 5.66E-6, I can multiply it and write data on the new variable as 8.5E6, but it won't get printed on screen with number_format, or works as intended on API.

Comment: `echo number_format($newnumber,10);` -> output: `0.0000085000` (wich is the same as 8.5E-6). [The second param is the decimals you want to show](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `echo $newnumber` is `8.5E-6` then that number as decimal should be `0.0000085`.
[number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) takes the amount of decimals you want to show as second parameter (defaults to 0). Since you have a x10-6 number with one decimal you'll need at least 7 decimals.

```
echo number_format($newnumber, 7);
```

will output

```
0.0000085
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has fixed the problem, tho it is really weird, it prints the number 5.66E-6 to screen with decimal points without having problem, but wasn't writing the multiplied output.

Comment: I couldn't print the original number 5.66E-6 including decimals _without_ adding the second parameter: https://3v4l.org/CcREa